# Difficulty to repeat an entire loop with string in Java

Tags: java

I am new to programming and I started to practice with Java. In my exercice, im asked to write a program which calculates and prints out the sum of the digits of a number. Then it prints out all the divisors of the sum number.

The problem is that after that, i need to ask the user if they want to try another number and im not able to restart the program when the person answer "yes" . Thank you and sorry for my english !

```
//Introduction
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to our Calculation Program!\n----------------------------------------");



        System.out.print("Enter a number with at most 7-digits:");
        int input = mykeyboard.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;


        while (input > 0) {
            int add = input % 10;
            sum = sum + add;
            input = input / 10;


        }
        System.out.println("Sum of the digits of your input is: " + sum);
        System.out.print("The divisors of " + sum + " are as follows: " );
        for (int counter = 1; sum >= counter; counter++) {
            if (sum % counter == 0)
        System.out.print(counter + " ");





    } 

        System.out.println("\n\nDo you want to try another number?");
        Scanner mykeyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = mykeyboard2.nextLine();

        if (choice.equals("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number with a most 7-digits:");

            while (input > 0);
                int add = input % 10;
                sum = sum + add;
                input = input / 10;

                System.out.println("Sum of the digits of your input is: " + sum);
                System.out.print("The divisors of " + sum + " are as follows: " );
                for (int counter = 1; sum >= counter; counter++)
                    if (sum % counter == 0)
                        System.out.print(counter + " ");
```

} if (choice.equals("no")) {

```
System.out.println("Thanks and Have a Great Day!");
```

Comment: You should wrap your logic into separate method. Then in simple loop you can as user if he want to go again, and invoke your method if yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (input > 0);
```

This will go in an infinite loop. I think you put a `;` instead of `{`.

Should be `while (input > 0){`

**EDIT**:

```
System.out.println("\nWelcome to our Calculation Program!\n----------------------------------------");

while(true){


    System.out.print("Enter a number with at most 7-digits:");
    int input = mykeyboard.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;


    while (input > 0) {
        int add = input % 10;
        sum = sum + add;
        input = input / 10;


    }
    System.out.println("Sum of the digits of your input is: " + sum);
    System.out.print("The divisors of " + sum + " are as follows: " );
    for (int counter = 1; sum >= counter; counter++) {
        if (sum % counter == 0)
        System.out.print(counter + " ");

    } 

    System.out.println("\n\nDo you want to try another number?");
    Scanner mykeyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = mykeyboard2.nextLine();

    if (choice.equals("no")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ! but the problem is that i cannot write nothing in the console now after the user answered "yes" and the console ask Enter the a number with a most 7-digits:

Comment: because you haven't added `int input = mykeyboard.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;` before the second loop

Comment: Okay ! And how can I ask the question again after the user said yes (second loop) ? Basically I want to restart the program (and the question) until the user has answered no to the question.

Comment: check edit. You don't need 2 while if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make it so the loop restarts

```
        System.out.print("Enter a number with at most 7-digits:");
    int input = mykeyboard.nextInt();
    while(input != -1){
    int sum = 0;
        int add = input % 10;
        sum = sum + add;
        input = input / 10;



    System.out.println("Sum of the digits of your input is: " + sum);
    System.out.print("The divisors of " + sum + " are as follows: " );
    for (int counter = 1; sum >= counter; counter++) {
        if (sum % counter == 0)
    System.out.print(counter + " ");
    System.out.print("Do you want another number? If you dont type -1: ");
    input = mykeyboard.nextInt();
    }
```

The code will keep going until the user types -1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to implement it is using your choice variable to control a loop condition:

```
System.out.println("\nWelcome to our Calculation Program!\n----------------------------------------");

String choice = "yes";
while(choice.equals("yes")) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number with at most 7-digits:");
    int input = mykeyboard.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;


    while (input > 0) {
        int add = input % 10;
        sum = sum + add;
        input = input / 10;


    }
    System.out.println("Sum of the digits of your input is: " + sum);
    System.out.print("The divisors of " + sum + " are as follows: " );
    for (int counter = 1; sum >= counter; counter++) {
        if (sum % counter == 0)
    System.out.print(counter + " ");

    System.out.println("\n\nDo you want to try another number?");
    Scanner mykeyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    choice = mykeyboard2.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("Thanks and Have a Great Day!");
```